# System status - disabled/deleted fields on Smart Groups (5.24)

Tags: custom-fields, smartgroups, system-status

After upgrading to 5.24 I get the above message in system status.  I've disabled and re-enabled all smart groups but the message persists and I can't find any redundant custom fields.  The message shows no smart group name or custom field name so there's no clue what's wrong. There are no error messages in the log. This is a very small Drupal based system.  Here's the message:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

After upgrading a couple more installs both produced these system status messages linked to phantom smart groups. To clear them click the left of the 2 small icons, then click the smart group criteria to go into advanced search. Then it really doesn't matter what you set this search to, as after clicking search you then go ahead & create the phantom smart group & then delete it. The message will then disappear.  This is the same process you would use to deal with this error message where the smart group exists, but for those you simply update the smart group after the advanced search.

Comment: This did not help. The message keeps coming back.

Answer (score 0):

Thats a false alarm which is fixed in this [PR](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/16963).

Comment: The two new lines in Schema.php are exactly as I already have it in 5.4.2. So this seems to be already in 5.4 but isn't working?  Here's what I have:
          list(, $customFieldID) = explode('_', $formValues[0]);
          if (!in_array((int) $customFieldID, $customFieldIds, TRUE)) {

Comment: clear civi cache

Comment: Cache cleared already, but did it again (twice) just for you.  Makes no difference. This message has been there in 5.4.0, 5.4.1 and now 5.4.2 (if that helps)

Comment: I managed to get this message to go away by clicking on the left icon, and saving the smart group criteria that it came up with - which was empty so got all contacts.  So I had to give it a name as it was a new group.  Then the message disappeared.!

Comment: I installed another 5.24.2 upgrade and got 2 of these empty smart group errors. The only way to remove them, at present, is to do as I did above, ie create the empty smart group then delete it.

Comment: It still shows up in 5.28.3

Answer (score 0):

This issue present on 5.25.0

Hover over the edit button to get the ssID. Delete the saved search entity if there is no mapping. This can be done by API/database.

Agileware ref: SUP-18449

Comment: What can I do with that ssID? The number keeps changing when I save a new smart group and delete it afterwards.